# How do i put in in the right paths when i have different project folders?

Tags: reactjs, directory, format, jsx, subdirectory

I have created a react folder where you have everything as default. I want to import my MyApp.js file from the src folder. I have the main folder "Myproject" and then I have a folder called "src" with a file in it called MyApp.js. I have been sitting here for two hours and trying to figure it out and I am seriously going crazy because it has nothing to do with CODING! Coding is supposed to be the difficult part omg.

The thing I do is,
import MyApp.js from "./src/MyApp.js". The error i get, Module not found: Can't resolve './src/MyApp.js' in 'C:\Users\k12\projectdo\src'

Answer (score 0):

quoting your error:

`Module not found: Can't resolve './src/MyApp.js' in 'C:\Users\k12\projectdo\src'`

Based on `C:\Users\k12\projectdo\src` react is already looking in the src folder.

try:
`import MyApp.js from "./MyApp.js".`

EDIT:
I just spotted another issue with your import. It should be:
`import MyApp from "./MyApp.js".`
I actually never include the .js part I usually would do:
`import MyApp from "./MyApp".`

Comment: It doesent help

Comment: What file are you importing into? Is the file also in the source folder? Please post the exact path.

Answer (score 0):

"react" was not with capital R thats why.